# Classifying Transistor Amplifier

Tags: transistors

How would one classify this transistor based amplifier?

[image]

Comment: Why delete your own question so quickly?

Answer (score 2):

It's a common base amplifier. This might help you: http://www.ee.sc.edu/personal/faculty/simin/ELCT563/21%20BJT%20circuits,%20gain%20and%20design.pdf

or this if you want more general help: http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/transistor/common-base-amplifier-configuration.php

Comment: This answer is correct.  Rather than comparing a circuit to schematics of the three basic types, looking for similarities, you can analyze the circuit operation.  In this case the input signal goes the emitter, and the output comes from the collector, so the base is considered to be common to both input and output, hence common base.